# Apply migration on multiple schemas using Java and Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase, multi-tenant

I'm trying to apply migration over my multi tenant system where I have one database with multiple schemas,
And I do so by first getting all the tenants then loop over them and execute the update on `liquibase` after changing the schema, but it seems that the schema is not changed cause after performing the migration on the first tenant the second tenant throws an error complaining about table already exist.

```
    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        Liquibase liquibase = null;
        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname like 'tenant_%'");

            
            List<String> schemas = new ArrayList<>();
            while (result.next()) {
                schemas.add(result.getString(1));
            }
            
            for (String schemaName:schemas) {
                
                connection.setSchema(schemaName);

                Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
                database.setDefaultSchemaName(schemaName);

                log.info("Schema Name: {}",connection.getSchema());

                liquibase = new Liquibase(CHANGE_LOG_FILE, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
                liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
            }
        } catch (SQLException | DatabaseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(liquibase!=null) {
                liquibase.close();
            }
            if(statement!=null&&!statement.isClosed()) {
                statement.close();
            }
            if(connection!=null&&!connection.isClosed()){
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: the reason I made it in different loops and not using `try-with-resource` is that the connection closes after getting the first row of the result set and updating the database so I had to close it myself

Comment: This could be happening for a couple of reasons.  Do your changesets have a substitution property for schema in front of all the db objects?  For example ${schemaname}.tablename?  Are you using one databasechangelog table for the whole db?  If so, you need to change that and have each tenant have its own databasechangelog* tables.

Comment: No substitution of schema name and each tenant has it's own changelog table, and I found later that `connection.setSchema()` doesn't change the schema and stays on the first schema I connected to